# python for automatically open a web browser when scanning a barcode containing url

Tags: python-2.7, barcode

I have followed this answer in this post by Janekmuric [Industrial Handheld QRCode Scanner Open URL in Browser](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/30389/industrial-handheld-qrcode-scanner-open-url-in-browser). This python script there really help me but I have 2 questions: is there any way that it can read example.com/something-something instead of it has to be http://example.com/something-something. Also, the script here cut off anything behind ".com". My url has parts behind it. Is there anybody can help me modify this python code so it does not cut off anything after ".com"

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a codewriting service

Comment: Hi Foon, I am new to this so I am not entirely sure where I should post this. Would you have any suggestion on where I should post the question? Thanks!

Comment: the example uses a regular expression to filter out urls that start with https or http:                 urls = re.findall(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', chars).  you can remove that code and just accept anything as input for your webbrowser, although this might be dangerous if you don't trust the inpiut (QR code)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I don't believe that there is a library that does not require 'http://', as HTTP is needed to get any website.  You could do something like this:

```
import webbrowser
url = "http://" + str(url) #where url is the url gotten by the scanner


webbrowser.open(url)
```

To be More closer to your code, where it says `webbrowser.open(url)` just put `"http://` in front of the url string.


As for your second question, I'm confused.  You say at first,"the script here cut off anything behind ".com"".  But in the last sentence, you say the opposite,"modify this python code so it does not cut off anything after ".com":.  So does it cut off the before or after?